# Where can I find good Silverlight application XAML templates & themes?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, templates

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Does not have to be free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Silverlight Toolkit ships with 11 free Silverlight Themes.
Live demo @ http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203
The XAML files themselves also ship with the Silverlight Toolkit download.

On the bottom of the page I've linked to there's a collection of resources on Silverlight Toolkit themes I suggest you take a look at.

Additionally, companies like [Nukeation](http://www.nukeation.com/reuxables.aspx?id=catalog) and [XamlTemplates](http://www.xamltemplates.net/) ship a very limited collection of commercially available Silverlight Themes. However, those would often not interop natively with 3rd party controls (Silverlight Toolkit controls, ComponentOne, etc).

Answer (score 2):

[Expression Gallery Contributions](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Profile/en-US/?user=Tim%20Heuer&sp=expg) for Silverlight navigation application.

Answer (score 1):

What about

[Silverlight Themes, Silverlight Skins, Silverlight Templates](http://www.xamltemplates.net/sl/)

Answer (score 1):

http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html